Concerned about burnt paint near dryer

Should I be concerned about the burnt paint? What you see on the left is a dryer mounted on top of a washing machine. Also, what is the best way to treat and paint the affected area? Are there any heat resistant paints?

That looks more to be mold and rust stains in paint and drywall from a leak. The most likely source is the window,vent, (or whatever the opening is. ) above.
The source of the leak needs to be repaired and then the peeling paint scraped off and the mold killed. The area need to be explored to find how extensive the damage is. There may be wood needing to be replaced or metal that is rusted.
This need a thorough inspection. It is not burned paint.

Burnt paint that far from the dryer should have more signs.  Like a house burnt down around it.
